# Unplugged battery, now screen won't turn on.

Tags: display, battery

I have posted previously on this site about my battery no longer charging after leaving in hot car for an hour or two - it would turn on only when connected but not charge. I just now took off the the back to my Asus Q502la laptop and noticed that the battery connector was a little loose. I removed the Asus Li-ion B41N1341 Battery Pack and reconnected it. I reassembled the system and attempted to turn in without the AC Adaptwr plugged in and it WORKED! But now things are worse...it powers on and even appears to charge, however the touch screen of the laptop is not working. So my computer is currently unusable as the computer starts but no images appear on the screen.

Please help, I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

If you can use the system without the battery, then the battery could be going out. That's a poor man's test for battery issues with laptops.

If it's under warranty, you might be covered. Not sure about batteries. If out of warranty, see if there is an alternative to the factory which might save you some money.

If you purchased this retail from a dealer, then contact them. You can always call ASUS but unless you speak Mandarin, I wouldn't recommend it unless you have a lot of patience and a good sense of humor. They're nice and friendly but the language barrier makes it an exercise in futility.

Answer (score 0):

So, after months of trying to figure this out myself - without taking it into a shop - I figured out the extremely simple solution to this. I am going to post this answer to all other threads that I have posted with regard to this, just in case somebody else has a similar issue regarding a like-modeled laptop. I'm not saying that this is a universal solution, but it is one that worked for me and was so simple that I simply overlooked it.

The connections between many of the hardware components of this laptop are extremely delicate and connect by nothing more than an adhesive and a small piece of black tape. With my situation having been that I left my computer in a hot car for too long, I assumed that it was heat damage to the battery and I would need a replacement. I took the back off of my computer yesterday for fun (I'll post a video at the end of this that shows a person I do not know disassembling a very similar computer if you need help) in an attempt to view the cpu. While doing this I decided it would be a good idea to remove the - in the words of an Asus rep from a phone call I made - "not removable battery" from the system so that I could take note of the model number. In doing so, it was then that I learned about the weak adhesive tape. I realized that the battery seemed to be partially disconnected, presumably because the heat of the car softened the adhesive and the connection shifted. I reconnected the battery and reassembled the computer and fired her up. Then, BAM! The battery worked WITHOUT the charger! How happy I must have been, until I realized the screen would not fire up. So I panicked, thinking that I broke it while taking it apart. I went back into the computer again and realized that the connection from the touch screen to the motherboard crossed over the connection to the battery and used the same weak adhesive and little back tape. I inspected and saw that it was peeled up slightly. This told that while I was handling the battery, I accidentally moved that chord. I reconnected/retaped it down and fired of the computer. Voila.

Thanks everybody for the help, I really appreciate it. And I'm glad that I got this fixed.

Here is the link to this taking it apart. This isn't me, and if you're careful you wont break the clips like he did...
 https://youtu.be/PjCtMtTdB7Q

Take care!